# Excel dump takes long time

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, excel, asp-classic

So what I have is an asp page that allows my user to hit a button and it will generate a dump of data from our sql server containing about 100k rows and 23 columns to an excel file. This takes about 10+ minuets. Should it be taking that long?

Comment: What are you using to do the dump?  Excel Automation?

Comment: I am told we are using this here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ExportClassLibrary.aspx

Comment: is that really creating an excel file or just a csv?

Comment: It seems that it allows your to do either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't really clear if your bottleneck is the generation of the excel file itself; but if this is the case, I can highly recommend [NativeExcel.Net](http://www.nika-soft.com/nativeexcelnet/index.htm) for performing the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an average of 15 characters per cell, that's about 34 megs of data in that excel file.

Yes, that will take some time..but your query or table indexes may also not be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the first steps you need to take to troubleshoot the problem:

1. Measure how long it is taking to retrieve the data.
2. Measure how long it is taking to create the excel file from that data.
3. Measure how long it takes to transmit that file to your user.

If it is not then obvious if something is taking too long, post the results here.

Comment: Using the ants profiler its says about 72% of time was spent on the export function and about 25% of the time on fetching the data.

Comment: @Breander: Given that this is the case, I'd recommend having a look at NativeExcel.Net; we evaluated quite a few libraries for exporting directly to excel and found this one to be the fastest by far.